# Mean matrix out of list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a simple and nice answer to this question?

I have a given list "l" of matrices (with same ncol & nrow).

```
l<-lapply(1:10,function(x){
  matrix(runif(100),ncol=10)
})
```

I want the mean of every cell.
I could do that with a for loop, but there should be a better solution!

With two matrices I could do it with (m1+m2)/2.
But `+` accepts only two parameters, so I cant do it like that:

```
do.call(.Primitive("+"),l) / length(l)
```

I'm looking forward for some nice answers :)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) Reduce**

```
Reduce("+", l) / length(l)
```

**2) simlify2array/apply** A bit longer than (1); however, it does have the advadntage of readily extending to functions other than `mean`:

```
apply(simplify2array(l), 1:2, mean)
```

**3) tapply**  Not as simple as (1) but like (2) it extends to functions other than `mean`:

```
array(tapply(unlist(l), sequence(lengths(l)), mean), dim(l[[1]]))
```

**4) rowMeans**

```
array(rowMeans(matrix(unlist(l),, length(l))), dim(l[[1]]))
```